# Best practice for long running tasks in onPause method

Tags: android

Android 0.8.11

Hello,

I have a App that uses a sqlite3 database and will save the contents which could be a few hundred records that will grow.

The records are loaded using the splash screen. However, when the user closes the app with the back button the items will be saved. However, this could take a long time.

What would be the impact of running a long running task. Could android kill it and corrupt the database?

Is could it be possible to create a thread during the onPause or would this be bad practice?

Thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: The Service will give a good approach.

Comment: use a Service + AsyncQueryHandler as a background working horse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to start an `IntentService` that will do the heavy job for you. As far as the `onResume` and `onPause` methods are executed on the ui thread they must be executed as fast as possible otherwise may cause screen freezing and ANR errors. So the only thing you should do is to start the service in your `onPause` method and leave it to do its job :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting a thread from your `onPause` call is a bad pratice and you might loose some data :
In the javadoc, you can read (emphasis mine) :

> In situations where the system needs more memory it may kill paused processes to reclaim resources. Because of this, you should be sure **that all of your state is saved by the time you return from this function**.

If you start a thread in `onPause` to make it return faster, this thread may be killed while it save your data.

You should probably save your record incrementally during the life of your activity, to avoid needing to save them all in one step when the user leaves your application. You could also offload the task to a background service but you have to be carefull not to loose any data as a service might get killed too.